# Only 10 CustomViewCells are originating right

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite

There's a strange issue with some of things I am using. Custom tableViewCell or db. In My app I made subclassing of UITableViewCell. My subviews are not transparent, so there shouldn't be scrolling issues or impact on productivity. They look fine and only the problem is that I can see only 10 first cells, that after I am getting the same names of the NAME label and others repeated, while are fetching the right ids from database. It looks like

CAT id=12 >> DOG id=18

And in the place of CAT should be DOG. Clicking on CAT cell, I am getting DOG title. So it says, the label of viewCell is lier.

I tried to run same db selects in SQLiteStudio and they are OK. I am getting the full set of records. Did someone face the same issue and where's the evil?

The DBAccess method:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getNominals:(int)subCountryID
{
NSMutableArray *nominals=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
const char* sqlNominals=sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT noms.nominalID, noms.nominal,noms.nominalName,noms.nominalImg,noms.priority\
FROM nominals AS noms\
INNER JOIN NominalsAndSubCountriesRelation as rel\
ON noms.nominalID=rel.NominalID\
WHERE rel.SubcountruID=%i\
ORDER BY noms.priority",subCountryID);

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlNominals, -1, &statement, NULL);

if ( sqlResult== SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        Nominal *nom=[[Nominal alloc]init];
        nom.nominalID=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        char *nominal=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        char *nominalName=(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
        char *nominalImg=(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
        nom.nominal=(nominal)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:nominal]: @"";
        nom.nominalName=(nominalName)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:nominalName]: @"";
        nom.nominalImg=(nominalImg)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:nominalImg]: @"";
        [nominals addObject:nom];
        [nom release];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
else
{
    [self dbConnectionError];
}
return nominals;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.nominalsArr count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NominalsCustomCell *cell =(NominalsCustomCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[NominalsCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    Nominal *nominalsObj=[self.nominalsArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [cell setTheNominals:nominalsObj];
}
return cell;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The evil will be in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Please post code from the `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

Comment: @jrturton I thought about it as well, but couldn't find any issue in this method. Thinking logically you are right. Such troubles are usually originating because of errors in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the following code

```
Nominal *nominalsObj=[self.nominalsArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[cell setTheNominals:nominalsObj];
```

outside of the `if (cell == nil)` block, since it should be set whenever a cell is set up, no matter if new or a reused one. In your case you're setting up data for only the newly created cells - reused ones are simply brought up by UITableView and displayed with originally set up data.

Read some more about how the UITableView cell reusing works.

Comment: Oh, thank you. How I couldn't see it by myself. By the way, why even 10 new cells have been created while scrolling the tableView?

Comment: Depending of your cells' height, those currently visible on the screen plus one or two that will appear when scrolling up or down may make together 10 live cells used by `UITableView`. In my app, with three custom section headers and a navigation toolbar, 9 are visible on the screen already.

Comment: No problem. Even being well aware of how the cell reusing works, I sometimes make that mistake myself. :)